# Dynamic memory allocation for 3D array

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Malloc a 3-Dimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306172/malloc-a-3-dimensional-array-in-c)
>   [dynamic allocation/deallocation of 2D & 3D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824363/dynamic-allocation-deallocation-of-2d-3d-arrays)

How can i allocate 3D arrays using malloc?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306172/malloc-a-3-dimensional-array-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = malloc(num_elem * num_elem * num_elem * sizeof(array_elem));
```

Why not? :)

Comment: My bad, poor explanation. Of course, there's num_elem_x, num_elem_y and num_elem_z.

Comment: @AareP, it's simpler to allocate the memory, but not simpler to use. You can't use the normal [i][j][k] syntax with this.

Comment: @Poita_, added an answer to this page about this indexing syntax..

Answer (score 19):

There are two different ways to allocate a 3D array.  You can allocate it either as a 1D array of pointers to a (1D array of pointers to a 1D array).  This can be done as follows:

```
 int dim1, dim2, dim3;
 int i,j,k;
 double *** array = (double ***)malloc(dim1*sizeof(double**));

        for (i = 0; i< dim1; i++) {

         array[i] = (double **) malloc(dim2*sizeof(double *));

          for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {

              array[i][j] = (double *)malloc(dim3*sizeof(double));
          }

        }
```

Sometimes it is more appropriate to allocate the array as a contiguous chunk.  You'll find that many existing libraries might require the array to exist in allocated memory.  The disadvantage of this is that if your array is very very big you might not have such a large contiguous chunk available in memory.

```
const int dim1, dim2, dim3;  /* Global variables, dimension*/

#define ARR(i,j,k) (array[dim2*dim3*i + dim3*j + k])
double * array = (double *)malloc(dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(double));
```

To access your array you just use the macro:

```
ARR(1,0,3) = 4;
```

Comment: 1) Don't cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `double ***` etc. is not a 3D array and it cannot be used as one! It only happens to use the same syntax as one uses for 3D array when indexing an entry, but has very different semantics as the complicated nested allocation already shows.

Answer (score 6):

This would work

```
int main()
{

    int ***p,i,j;

    p=(int ***) malloc(MAXX * sizeof(int **));

    for(i=0;i<MAXX;i++)
    {
        p[i]=(int **)malloc(MAXY * sizeof(int *));
        for(j=0;j<MAXY;j++)
            p[i][j]=(int *)malloc(MAXZ * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(k=0;k<MAXZ;k++)
        for(i=0;i<MAXX;i++)
            for(j=0;j<MAXY;j++)
                p[i][j][k]=<something>;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `double ***` etc. is not a 3D array and it cannot be used as one! It only happens to use the same syntax as one uses for 3D array when indexing an entry, but has very different semantics as the complicated nested allocation already shows.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody still wants to use 3-dimensional array allocated in one big chunk, here's how you add normal indexing to it:

```c
void*** newarray(int icount, int jcount, int kcount, int type_size)
{
    void*** iret = (void***)malloc(icount*sizeof(void***)+icount*jcount*sizeof(void**)+icount*jcount*kcount*type_size);
    void** jret = (void**)(iret+icount);
    char* kret = (char*)(jret+icount*jcount);
    for(int i=0;i<icount;i++)
        iret[i] = &jret[i*jcount];
    for(int i=0;i<icount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<jcount;j++)
            jret[i*jcount+j] = &kret[i*jcount*kcount*type_size+j*kcount*type_size];
    return iret;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `double ***` etc. is not a 3D array and it cannot be used as one! It only happens to use the same syntax as one uses for 3D array when indexing an entry, but has very different semantics as the complicated nested allocation already shows.

Answer (score 0):

For a given type T (non-contiguous):

```
size_t dim0, dim1, dim2;
...
T ***arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * dim0); //type of *arr is T **
if (arr)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < dim0; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i] * dim1); // type of *arr[i] is T *
    if (arr[i])
    {
      size_t j;
      for (j = 0; j < dim1; j++)
      {
        arr[i][j] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i][j] * dim2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unless you are working with a *very* old (pre-C89) implementation, you do not need to cast the result of `malloc()`, and the practice is discouraged.  If you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc()` in scope, the compiler will type it to return `int`, and you'll get an "incompatible type for assignment"-type warning.  If you cast the result, the warning is suppressed, and there's no guarantee that a conversion from a pointer to an `int` to a pointer again will be meaningful.

Comment: `double ***` etc. is not a 3D array and it cannot be used as one! It only happens to use the same syntax as one uses for 3D array when indexing an entry, but has very different semantics as the complicated nested allocation already shows.