# Stack memory use continuous dynamically allocated array vs statically

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, stack

I'm working with 3D and 4D arrays of variable sizes and they have to be continuous (**sometimes** is easier call as `*(&x[0][0][0] + k)` than the '`x[][][]`' way). 'Cause of the variable size of the array, I need to allocate dynamically. I found this code, in another answer ([Dynamic memory allocation for 3D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438142/dynamic-memory-allocation-for-3d-array)) to do that and it works fine, but I don't know how much memory use of the stack.

```c
double ***arr3dAlloc(const int ind1, const int ind2, const int ind3) {
    int i;
    int j;
    double ***array = (double***)malloc((ind1 * sizeof(double*)) + 
                                        (ind1 * ind2 * sizeof(double**)) + 
                                        (ind1 * ind2 * ind3 * sizeof(double)));
    for (i = 0; i < ind1; ++i) {
        array[i] = (double**)(array + ind1) + i * ind2;
        for (j = 0; j < ind2; ++j) {
            array[i][j] = (double*)(array + ind1 + ind1 * ind2) + i * ind2 * ind3 + j * ind3;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

the question is:

- What is the difference between `double ***arr1 = arr3dAlloc(N1,N2,N3);` and `double arr2[N1][N2][N3];`
- Given that `arr2` uses `N1*N2*N3*sizeof(double)` memory of the stack, how much memory does `arr1` use? Only `sizeof(double***)`?
- In general, is there a method to measure the use of stack memory of any variable?

Comment: There is no 3D or 4D array and nothing which can be used as one. Also being a 3-star programmer is definitvely no compliment in C. Most times it is a signal of poor design.

Comment: The code is for scientific porpouse, so the array*** is something like `population[J][K][N]` where the J and K index represent the cells of a spatial grid and N is for the population number of the cell i,j. The brute part of the code use pointers to the first element and make some computations, but some of functions to computate must be easily editable and readable so i would like to use the population[i][j][n] notation. I need to run several simulation with the same scheme but differents 'special functions' so stopping all the time to think 'in what place of memory am i' is not optimal

Comment: `double ***` is **not** an array or even a similar data structure! A pointer is not an array. And tp pointers don't make a 2D array, 3 not an 3D array. Why not use a true array if you need one? The wild casts already should make you suspisious. You don't even allocate the correct memory.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer has size of a pointer with the respective machine architecture
(nowadays often `long` or `long long`). That size is independent of the type of the memory being referenced. (A "`**`" is just referring to another pointer.)

An array *type[N]* is always allocating *sizeof(type)*N* byte of memory. `sizeof()` includes padding of type to proper alignment boundary. 
Thus, using `malloc(sizof(type)*N)` will allocate sufficient memory for an array of *N* elements of *type*, providing a pointer to the allocated piece of memory. You may use `calloc()` for also getting the memory initialized to zero.

As the allocated memory is not dependent on the organisation of a multi-dimensional array, such an approach will work for any number of dimensions >=1.

To address your questions:

- `double ***arr1 = …` is just storing the pointer to some memory area, 
  while `arr2[N1][N2][N3]` is allocating padded space for `N1*N2*N3` doubles.
- `arr1` uses `sizeof(void *)` bytes, 
  while  `arr2` is using `N1*N2*n3*sizeof(double)` bytes.
- `sizeof(var)` always gives the size of the variable, 
  whether this is being in data/bss segment or on stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your code allocates a 3D array and a array of pointers to arrays of pointers to `double` to access its elements via double indirections.  There are some issues with this approach:

- Your code does not align the `double` array on a `double` boundary. If the size of a pointer if 4 bytes and the array has size 3x4x5, the `double` array will be misaligned, which may cause undefined behavior on some systems.
- The types used in your size computations are approximate.
- Type `int` might overflow when computing the size of very large matrices.

Here is a corrected version (assuming all pointer types have the same size):

```
double ***arr3dAlloc(int ind1, int ind2, int ind3) {
    size_t level1_size = sizeof(double**) * ind1;
    size_t level2_size = sizeof(double*) * ind1 * ind2;
    size_t padding = (sizeof(double) - (level1_size + level2_size) % sizeof(double))
                      % sizeof(double);
    size_t level3_size = sizeof(double) * ind1 * ind2 * ind3;
    int i, j;
    double ***array = calloc(1, level1_size + level2_size + padding + level3_size);
    double *array3d = (double*)((unsigned char*)array + level1_size + level2_size + padding);
    for (i = 0; i < ind1; ++i) {
        array[i] = (double**)(array + ind1) + i * ind2;
        for (j = 0; j < ind2; ++j) {
            array[i][j] = array3d;
            array3d += ind3;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Note that with C99, you can allocate real 3D arrays that you can use directly in your main computational code:

```
/* array3d is a pointer to an allocated 3D array: */
double (*array3d)[ind2][ind3] = calloc(sizeof(*array3d), ind1);

/* array3d can be used like a statically defined array: */
for (int i = 0; i < ind1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ind2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ind3; k++) {
            array3d[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the types used in your size computations are approximate'?  The computation seems to be in terms of pointers and integers, which are not approximate types.  I'll need to think whether the values used are only approximately correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: for example `(ind1 * sizeof(double*)) + (ind1 * ind2 * sizeof(double**))` should be `(ind1 * sizeof(double**)) + (ind1 * ind2 * sizeof(double*))`... It does not matter much, since I also make the assumption that all pointers have the same size.

Comment: Ah, I see — yes, technically, there's a mismatch between the pointer types used in the sizeof operators, but as you say, `sizeof(double *) == sizeof(double **)` on all actual systems.  (The standard requires `void *` and `char *` to be the same size; it requires all structure pointers to be the same size; it requires all union pointers to be the same size; it doesn't lay any requirements on pointers to other objects, including pointers to pointers.  That's §6.2.5 Types, ¶28 in the C11 standard.)

Comment: A lot of info to understand in a couple of minutes! the code isn't mine, is an answer of another question but i think that im starting to understand what you say... The use of `size_t` insted of directly use indX in `calloc()` is for the "`int` issue" of large matrices ? and why is the padding in `*array3d` ? there is empty space between `&array[i][j][0]` and `&array[i][j+1][0]`?
Talking about the C99 approach: Can i call `array3d` from outside of the main, where ind1,ind2,ind3 are unknown ?? sorry if this are newbie questions...

Comment: how do you measure the padding size ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues to address here.

The first is the difference between global variables, heap, and stack. These are all portions of RAM. malloc() allocates a portion of the heap and returns a pointer. This is discussed in many other places on the Internet.

The other issue is compile-time versus run-time allocation. For compile-time allocation, the size of the array must be known in advance. Your example uses run-time allocation (`malloc()`), because the size of the array is passed into the function as variables. It is not possible to allocate the array on the stack or in globals without knowing its size at compile time.