# How to allocate 3d matrix dynamically in c programming language?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

How to allocate 3d matrix dynamically in c programming where dimension will be [50][n][n] ;
where n , I am taking through command line .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic memory allocation for 3D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438142/dynamic-memory-allocation-for-3d-array)

Comment: Another duplicate covering any number of dimensions: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: yes but value is not modifying after one row

Comment: @Nirajsingh: which value is not being modified?  Can you edit your question to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: There was an bug i solved it..thank you

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports C99 and beyond you can use automatic Variable Length Array (VLA):

```
int arr[50][n][n];
```

If `n` is expected to be large then you can allocate VLA on dynamic storage:

```
int (*arr)[n][n] = malloc(50 * sizeof *arr);
```

In both cases individual elements are accessed by `arr[i][j][k]`.

Comment: i dont know why i am not able to modify array allocated with this.Value is not changing

Comment: @Nirajsingh, please put your code and description what is wrong to the question