# How do 2-D arrays and dynamic allocation work?

Tags: c, malloc, multidimensional-array

So my idea:

A 2-D array is an array of arrays. If an array is X by Y, then each X points  to an array with length Y. Is that part correct? Is that why also when you want to dynamically allocate an array in C you have to say

```
array=(type **)malloc(X*sizeof(type *)).
```

The type `*` is to tell  the compiler that each array index will be a pointer to another array so it should be sufficiently big enough to hold pointers o array?

Also why is this loop needed?

```
for(i =0;i<X;i++)
{
array[i]=(type *)malloc(Y*sizeof(type))
}
```

Is the cast

```
(type *)
```

needed because so that each index is a pointer to a 1-D array? But this time in the `malloc` we can just say (type) instead of `(type *)` because the index won't be holding pointers any more?

*EDIT*

Oh..so this is just mimicking a 2-d array by having an each index in an 1-d array point to another 1-d array. Ok. In that case is my logic for why each malloc have that specific argument make sense? 
The code here is taken from this SO question 
[dynamic allocation/deallocation of 2D & 3D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824363/dynamic-allocation-deallocation-of-2d-3d-arrays)

Comment: For starters, that isn't a 2D array. its an 1D array of pointers. A 2D array is declared as `Type arr[N][M];` where N and M are the dimensions you want. A pointer array is often used to mimic this behavior, but they are *not* the same.

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't involve an actual 2D array.  This is a 2D array:

```
int myArray[X][Y];
```

It involves no pointers.

Your code involves a pointer to an array of pointers, which isn't the same thing.

---

> Why is this loop needed?

Because otherwise all of the pointers in your array of pointers don't point at any storage.

---

> Is the cast needed?

No.

Comment: +1 Why I always use N before M i'll never understand. Maybe its a genetic thing =P